# Select 1 row from each category of photos

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have 2 table Monuments and Photos

### Monument Table

> Monument_Id    int
>
> MonumentName  nvarchar

### Photos Tabls

> Photo_Id    int
>
> Monument_Id int
>
> URL nvarchar

In some monuments there are more then 50 images and some are empty. I just want to display only 1 image of each monument and ignore the monument which don't have image.

tried my best but was not able to make it work.

Regards
thanks

Comment: Which image? A random one? An arbitrary (but not random) one? A specific one?

Comment: random image will also do or first image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify **which** of those up to 50 images you want to have - but something along those lines will work: you can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) with the `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
;WITH OneImagePerMonument AS
(
   SELECT 
       m.Monument_ID, m.MonumentName, p.Photo_Id, p.URL,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.Monument_ID ORDER BY Photo_Id DESC) AS 'RowNum')
   FROM dbo.Monument m
   INNER JOIN dbo.Photos p ON m.Monument_Id = p.Monument_Id
)
SELECT 
   Monument_ID, MonumentName, Photo_Id, URL
FROM OneImagePerMonument
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

This CTE "partitions" your data by `Monument_Id`, and for each partition, the `ROW_NUMBER` function hands out sequential numbers, starting at 1 and ordered by `Photo_Id DESC` - so the latest row gets `RowNum = 1` (for each `UserID`) which is what I select from the CTE in the SELECT statement after it.